# "Transform" a mesh into another programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I need some way to transform my mesh into another by adding or subtracting triangles and vertices and changing their position.

My goal is to transform my "Monster"(that is a single mesh) into a human(that is a single mesh too) smoothly inside Unity.
Something that looks like the "Crumple Mesh Modifier" that you can find in this project [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/5141)

sorry about my english, I`m not an English speeker and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic creation of a mesh:

```
MeshFilter meshFilter = GetComponent();
Mesh mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;

if (mesh == null){
    meshFilter.mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
}

Vector3 p0 = new Vector3(0,0,0);
Vector3 p1 = new Vector3(1,0,0);
Vector3 p2 = new Vector3(0,1,0);
Vector3 p3 = new Vector3(0,0,1);

// clear mesh of current data
mesh.Clear();

// set vertices
mesh.vertices = new Vector3[]{p0,p1,p2,p3};

// set 
mesh.triangles = new int[]{
    0,1,2,
    0,2,3,
    2,1,3,
    0,3,1
};
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
mesh.RecalculateBounds();
mesh.Optimize();
```

Modifying existing vertices (would work similarly for faces):

```
// mesh.vertices returns a copy
Vector3[] vert_copy = mesh.vertices;
vert_copy[0] = new Vector3(10,11,12);
vert_copy[1] = new Vector3(13,14,15);

// reassign new vertices to mesh
mesh.vertices = vert_copy;

mesh.RecalculateNormals();
mesh.RecalculateBounds();
mesh.Optimize();
```

These calls get expensive when you recalculate the normals and the bounds.  If your mesh will not physically interact with other meshes while "transforming" you can defer  **RecalculateBounds()** until after the "transformation" is complete.  Similarly, if you anticipate only small per-frame transformations to your mesh you could limit **RecalculateNormals()** to every other frame or every 300ms.